# Curvature formula for general regular curve

Tags: differential-geometry, curves, curvature, frenet-frame

If we have a curve $\gamma :(a,b)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n $. Then we have the same curve but with an arc length parametrisation $\hat{\gamma} $ such that $\gamma =\hat{\gamma } \circ s .$ (So $\hat{\gamma }$ has unit speed with respect to $s$.)
I'm looking at this proof of the general curvature formula which of course is $$\kappa(t)= \frac{||\gamma_{tt}\ \times \ \gamma_t ||}{||\gamma_t ||^3} .$$

In the proof we find $$\kappa (t)=\hat{\gamma }_{ss}(s(t))=\frac{\gamma _{tt}}{||\gamma_t ||^2}-\gamma_t\frac{\gamma_{tt}\cdot \gamma_t }{||\gamma_t ||^4 }. $$

**But** all of a sudden it jumps from this to
$$\kappa ^2(s(t))=\frac{||\gamma_{tt}||^2||\gamma_{t}||^2-(\gamma_{tt}\cdot \gamma_{t})^2}{||\gamma_{t}||^6}. $$

**So my question is...why?**

Comment: First of all, $\kappa$ is a scalar, so your "we find" equation makes no sense. Did you mistype? There are better ways of doing this.

Comment: Everything should be inside the norm. I wrote out the expression for $\gamma _{ss} $.

Comment: Have you tried computing the square of the length of that vector?

Comment: It looks too messy for me to do it without writing it out in terms of coordinates

Comment: No, you need to acquire basic algebra skills with dot products. But, as I said, this is not the optimal approach in the first place.

Comment: I suppose to get the norm of the expression squared that I can just take the dot product with itself. I didn't think of that until just now..